# Error while changing port for oracle XE 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, port

I am trying to change port of oracle xe 11g, as I am not able to open the link using default port 8080. I am getting below error.

```
SQL> Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(3010);
BEGIN DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(3010); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31024: Parser initialization failed with LPX-54 error
while parsing a stream to XOB
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 516
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XDB", line 645
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have run it connected as SYS or SYSTEM.

Comment: I am using SYSTEM user